# Javascript Profile Lookup

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following Javascript Problem shown below. I have been trying to figure out what part of it is failing and have been unsuccessful for some time. I do have solutions provided by the initial tutorial but am unclear as to why this is not quite working.

*We have an array of objects representing different people in our contacts lists.A lookUpProfile function that takes name and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you. The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property. If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact". If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property".*

```
// Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){ 

for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].length; j++){

if(contacts[i][0]===name&&contacts[i][j]===prop){ return contacts[i][j]    ;}

else if (contacts[i]===name) {return "No such property";}

else return "No such contact";
} 
  }

// Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @Kharel - no ... it's https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/blob/master/curriculum/challenges/english/02-javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup.english.md

Comment: `contacts[i]` is an OBJECT not an ARRAY - therefore has no `.length` property - therefore your inner loop never runs

Comment: alright @Jaromanda carry on then with your journey

Comment: @Kharel what???

Comment: i overlooked and thought you were the author @Jaromanda. Nevertheless carry-on

Comment: Ok, will do @Kharel :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the for-loop confusing you.
Question ask us to check if `name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"`.
So in your answer, you return `else if (contacts[i]===name) {return "No such property";}` as soon as you reached the first invalid contact, which is not the question wanted.
You should leave your `return "No such contact"` out of the for loop as a final catch-all.

Other than that, when you need to check if a property exists in an object, you can use `Object.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)`.
`contacts[i]` in `else if (contacts[i]===name) {return "No such property";}` will give you the actual object in contacts, it will never match the `name`.
You will need to get the `name` with bracket or dot annotation.
Example:

```
contacts[0] is equal to
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}
contacts[0].firstName is equal to "Akira"
contacts[0]["firstName"] is equal to "Akira"
```

See the hint of the question:
[Click me go to the hint page](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/freecodecamp-challenge-guide-profile-lookup/18259)

```js
// Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
    // Only change code below this line
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        const contact = contacts[i];
        if (contact.firstName === name && contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contact[prop];
        } else if (contact.firstName === name && !contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
    // Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Answer (score 1):

Find profile first, then property second

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  const profile = contacts.find((contact) => contact.firstName === name)
  if (!profile) return "No such contact"

  const property = profile[prop]
  if (!property) return "No such property"

  return property
}
```

```js
// Setup
var contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
]

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const profile = contacts.find((contact) => contact.firstName === name)
  if (!profile) return "No such contact"

  const property = profile[prop]
  if (!property) return "No such property"

  return property
  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"))
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bkira", "likes"))
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "nikes"))
```

Comment: Thanks - I am really looking more for what the issue is in the code I wrote - I know there are many ways to redo it or many ways to come up with a valid solution. I just can't figure out what the issue is with my code